# HTML 5 and Javascript Drag and Drop

Tags: php, javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am having an issue with http://jsfiddle.net/Hh8qJ/ I know of two major problems. One does not work in Safari(and probably Internet Exploder). It seems as if options in Safari may not be able to be made into a dragable object? Also in Firefox, the options do not deselect when dropped. This is part of a bigger project, so I will describe somewhat what I am trying to accomplish and why I ventured down the path that I did. So I chose the drop down so that elements could be inserted to and from it, and if needed items could be put in different places in the drop down. In the larger project, there will only be one of these drop downs, and many of the drop-zone divs. The items will be dragged from the drop down into many of these drop fields, but in certain cases may need to go backwards. I am not really sure if there is a better way to do this, but this is what I came up with. I would like to avoid JQuery.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: The HTML was there because I had to put in some code and figured that no one wanted the full file here.

I will try to give a more concise example of how this could be actually used. Say I have 4 boxes, with car names. The boxes say saab, volvo, ford, and dodge. The task would be to drag from the drop down all of the cars into there respectable drop zone. Then if the user wanted to put the cars back in the drop down, they could drag them back into the drop down from the drop zone and it would then place them back into alphabetical order. (I do know there is not code now to do the alpabetizing, but I was trying one hurdle at a time.) Keep in mind, this is a very small scale example of how I have plans to use this for a much larger project, this is just an attempt that I am making to make the issue I am having as simple as possible.

```
  <html>
```

Comment: here in peace of code-box what `<html>` mean?

Comment: jquery is your friend meant to solve some of the cross browser problems you are describing. you should revise your question to give a more clear understanding of the problem - also in fewer words. this will help us help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1, #div2
{float:left; width:100px; height:150px; margin:10px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
 ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
 ev.preventDefault();

 var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
 ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
function sort(uList)
{
  var listItem = document.getElementById(uList).getElementsByTagName('li');
  var listLength = listItem.length;
  var list = [];
  for(var i=0; i<listLength; i++)
  list[i] = listItem[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
  list.sort();
  for(var i=0; i<listLength; i++)
  listItem[i].firstChild.nodeValue = list[i];
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragend="sort('div1')">

    <li id="list-item3"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">a</li>
    <li id="list-item5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">b</li>
    <li id="list-item2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">c</li>
    <li id="list-item4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">d</li>
</ul>
<ul id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragend="sort('div2')"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps :). I used HTML 5 on it. After an item has been dragged from one list to the other, the function sort() will be called. This function will be the one to sort the items inside the list. I havent tried it yet on form elements but ill see what i can do.

Comment: btw.. might be better if you just used checkboxes.

Comment: Thank your help! A few issues, one you can "wedge" these pieces in between each other, which you can try in http://jsfiddle.net/gu9ZT/ Try to drop it in the padding area and you will see what I mean. Also when that happens then the top one drags two elements. Also in some cases it seems when you are too far right of the word or if you drag down while moving an item, more than one item can be moved at a time. Here is another way I thought of, which solves the overlap issue. http://jsfiddle.net/gjcPd/ With you example on sort, I may be able to implement the sorting. In mine as well sometimes

Comment: CONTINUATION: I still have the issue of multiples will move at one time. This might be a nice feature in the future, and might be nice to implement, but for now its too buggy and unpredictable, but it may be nice in the future to be able to for example select the top one and be able to use the shift key an select the bottom one, so then multiple items could be moved at once. For now maybe there would be a way to check if multiple are moving and then only allow the first one? Thanks!